# redirect if page down from user perspective

Tags: javascript, http, redirect

is it possible to redirect to a page, and if that page is down redirect somewhere else, being that the first redirect is a localserver page on the client network and outside the first server?

I have found this:

img src="http://www.rgagnon.com/images/pdf.gif" onload="window.location='http://www.rgagnon.com';" onerror="window.location='http://www.google.com';"

But it makes the "outside" server check if the "inside" page is up so it doesn't work. It would be something that runs on the client level.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I did understand correct, you are trying to check if image is loaded on page. If not you are redirect the user to google let say. Question why you are redirecting the user if image is loaded correct?

Give more details what you want to do here.

Anyway this will perform the check if page is accessible (jquery + ajax) and redirect user if you successfully image is loaded or if image fails to load.

```
    $('#your_img_id')
    .load(function(){
        $.ajax('http://www.rgagnon.com'), {
             statusCode: {
             404: function() {
             alert("not working");
             window.location='http://www.google.com'
             },
             200: function() {
             alert("working");
             window.location='http://www.rgagnon.com';
             }
          }
       });  
    })
    .error(function(){
        window.location='http://www.google.com';
    });
```

**Updated:**

For all anchors on your page add new attribute with secondary page if href is locally.

```
<body>
<a href="http://www.rgagnon.com/page-1.html" fallbackhref="http://www.google.com/page-1" />
<a href="http://www.rgagnon.com/page-2.html" fallbackhref="http://www.google.com/page-2" />
<a href="http://www.rgagnon.com/page-3.html" fallbackhref="http://www.google.com/page-3" />
</body>
```

Now overwrite href with fallback values if initial href is innacesible

```
$("a").each(function() {
    //exit if hreffallback undefiend
    if ($(this).attr('fallbackhref')== undefined) return;
    $.ajax($(this).attr('href')), {
             statusCode: {
             404: function() {
             alert("not working");
             $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('fallbackhref'));
             },
             200: function() {
             alert($(this).attr('href') + " accesible");
             //do notihng                 
             }
          }
       });
});
```

If you thinking to redirect in other way it's impossible. If you will access you local website from otside www.rgagnon.com will not be accessible at all an not redirect is performed.

If you have this problem on your live website rewrite all your app and use relative paths without domains, instead href="www.rgagnon.com/your-page/" use href="/your-page/"

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not what I'm looking for. I'll try to ilustrate:

client(local network) --> server1 (internet) --> redirect to local network server --> if local network server is inaccessible (for client), redirect to other page.